# Nested triples with units on value in rdflib - > turtle file

Tags: python-3.x, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I'm currently making a turtle file. I have to relate values/units based on qudt.org
Based on example data shown below:

```
data = {    "objectid_l1": "Bridge_1",
            "defid_l1": "Bridge",
            "objectid_l2": "Deck_1",
            "defid_l2": "Deck",
            "variable": "height",
            "value": "50.0",
            "unit": "M",
}
```

i made the following code, but the output is not what i want:

```
from rdflib.namespace import RDF
from rdflib import URIRef, BNode, Literal, Namespace, Graph

EX = Namespace('https://example.com/id/') 
UNIT = Namespace('http://qudt.org/2.1/vocab/unit/')
BS = Namespace('https://w3id.org/def/basicsemantics-owl#')

for i in data:
        if i['objectid_l1'] != None:
                g.add((
                    EX[i['objectid_l1']],
                    RDF.type,
                    EX[i['defid_l1']]
                ))
                g.add((
                    EX[i['objectid_l1']],
                    BS['hasPart'],
                    EX[i['objectid_l2']]
                ))
                g.add((
                    EX[i['objectid_l1']],
                    EX[i['variable']],
                    EX[i['value']]
                ))
                g.add((
                    EX[i['variable']],
                    BS['unit'],
                    UNIT[i['unit']]
                ))
```

output:

```
ex:Bridge_1
  a ex:Bridge ;
  bs:hasPart ex:Deck_1 ;
  ex:height 50.0 .

50.0 bs:unit unit:M .
```

As output i want that the units indent, the desired output is as follows:

```
ex:Bridge_1
  a ex:Bridge ;
  bs:hasPart ex:Deck_1 ;
  ex:height [
      rdf:value 50.0 ;
      bs:unit unit:M ;
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few things missing in your code to achieve what you want :

- you need to explicitely create the blank node you show in the expected output, using rdflib `BNode`, then use it as subject of the triples setting the height value and the unit
- you have to specify that the height value (50.0) is a litteral value.

```
from rdflib.namespace import RDF, XSD, NamespaceManager
from rdflib import BNode, Literal, Namespace, Graph

EX = Namespace('https://example.com/id/') 
UNIT = Namespace('http://qudt.org/2.1/vocab/unit/')
BS = Namespace('https://w3id.org/def/basicsemantics-owl#')

g = Graph()
g.namespace_manager = NamespaceManager(Graph())
g.namespace_manager.bind('unit', UNIT)
g.namespace_manager.bind('bs', BS)
g.namespace_manager.bind('ex', EX)

i = {
    "objectid_l1": "Bridge_1",
    "defid_l1": "Bridge",
    "objectid_l2": "Deck_1",
    "defid_l2": "Deck",
    "variable": "height",
    "value": "50.0",
    "unit": "M",
}

if i['objectid_l1'] != None:
    g.add((EX[i['objectid_l1']], RDF.type, EX[i['defid_l1']]))
    g.add((EX[i['objectid_l1']], BS['hasPart'], EX[i['objectid_l2']]))

    bnode = BNode()
    g.add((bnode, RDF.value, Literal(i['value'])))
    g.add((bnode, BS['unit'], UNIT[i['unit']]))
    g.add((EX[i['objectid_l1']], EX[i['variable']], bnode))

g.serialize('test.ttl', format='ttl')
```

Should output as expected :

```
ex:Bridge_1 a ex:Bridge ;
    bs:hasPart ex:Deck_1 ;
    ex:height [ rdf:value "50.0" ;
            bs:unit unit:M ] .
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i just implemented your logic in my code and it just works great.